# Angular Material - Tabela com tamanho que se ajusta com a quantidade de dados que vem do banco

Tags: angular, angular-material

Consigo criar uma tabela no Angular, usando o Angular Material, que se adequa a quantidade de dados vinda do banco?

Já usei essa tabela do código abaixo e para cada coluna definia uma tag ng-container fixa, mas agora preciso que as colunas aumentem de acordo com os dados que vêm do banco, pois vou ter dados de horários de marcação de ponto em que deve aparecer uma nova coluna com o horário marcado a cada nova marcação do usuário (por exemplo, ele tem dois horários marcados para o dia -> 2 colunas, daí ele marca o ponto mais três vezes -> 5 colunas) e não posso limitar o número de marcações por dia.

Podem me dar alguma ideia, por favor?

```
<!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Precisa de mais informações sobre backend.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar ngFor com o ng-container, tendo um array com os header que você deseja, dessa forma que eu fiz abaixo só é necessário que seus dados estejam organizados de uma maneira que você consiga utilizar ou o index da coluna ou o nome do header para pegar os atributos.

```html
<!-- código ocultado -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="header">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ header }} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[header] }} </td> <!-- aqui você pode utilizar tanto o i(index) como o header pra buscar uma propriedade do seu elemento -->
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headers"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: headers"></tr>
<!-- código ocultado -->
```